# Error when reading txt file, can't read txt file correctly

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to get data from txt file (university data), (The topic requires working with txt files)
I don't understand why my program runs wrong, in the first loop it still gives correct result, next time it fails

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"

struct age{
    char id[10];
    char name[50];
    int numb;
    int score;
};
int main(){
    age dnu[20];
    char x[50];
    int d;
    int n;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("ex3","r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
    }
//  if( fgets(x,60,f)!=NULL){
//      puts(x);
//  }
    
    fscanf(f,"%d",&n);  
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        fscanf(f," %s ",&dnu[i].id);
        fscanf(f," %s ",&dnu[i].name);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&dnu[i].numb);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&dnu[i].score);
    }
    printf("%10s    %20s    %20s    %20s","majors","Name majors","number of students ","matriculation score\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%10s    %20s    %20d    %20d",dnu[i].id,dnu[i].name,dnu[i].numb,dnu[i].score);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

here is everything in the txt file

```
2
IT
Technology 
4252
27
SEO
Search Engine 
3421
30
```

this is images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrmtN.png)

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Please tag only the language you are using.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<1;i++)` only performs one iteration.  After that loop, you're then looping `n` times to output data that you did not initialize.  I notice from your screen shot that you are using an IDE for development.  That should come with a built-in debugger that allows you to step through your program's execution line by line.  If you do that, then you'll be able to see what it's actually doing.

Comment: @paddy I tried for more iterations ( n ) , but it still can't read everything in the txt file
(The last 4 lines in the txt file cannot be read properly)

Comment: Using `%s` will not handle spaces in a string, unless you tell it to delimit at the newline (_i.e._ `%[^\n]s`).  But you should not use `fscanf` for that anyway.  Use `fgets` to read a line (and don't forget to trim off the newline character, which is included when you do that).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the correct code

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
void delete_n(char a[]){
    size_t x=strlen(a);
        if(a[strlen(a)-1]=='\n'){
            a[strlen(a)-1]='\0';
        }
}
struct age{
    char id[10];
    char name[50];
    int numb;
    int score;
};
int main(){
    age dnu[20];
    char x[50];
    char xx[50];
    int d;
    int n;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("ex3","r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
    }
//  if( fgets(x,60,f)!=NULL){
//      puts(x);
//  }
    
    if(fgets(x,50,f)!=NULL){
//          printf("%s",x);
        }
    n=atoi(x);
//  printf("===%d===",n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(fgets(dnu[i].id,10,f)!=NULL){
//          printf("%s",dnu[i].id);
        }
        if(fgets(dnu[i].name,50,f)!=NULL){
//          printf("%s",dnu[i].name);
        }
//      fscanf(f," %[^\n]s ",&dnu[i].name);
        
        if(fgets(x,50,f)!=NULL){
//          printf("%s",x);
        }
        dnu[i].numb=atoi(x);
        if(fgets(xx,50,f)!=NULL){
//          printf("%s",xx);
        }
        dnu[i].score=atoi(xx);
    }
//  printf("===%s==",x);
    printf("%10s    %20s    %20s    %20s","majors","Name majors","number of students ","matriculation score\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        delete_n(dnu[i].id);
        delete_n(dnu[i].name);
        printf("%10s    %20s    %20d    %20d",dnu[i].id,dnu[i].name,dnu[i].numb,dnu[i].score);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

sorry for my english
ok, the questioner's code doesn't run properly because the program that reads the file defaults to a string, so you need to use a script to convert the string to an integer variable `atoi(x1 ,x2)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only-answers without any explanation are discouraged at SO. Please read [How-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information about how to create a good answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).